# fahrenheit to celsius, very curious why it didnt compile

Tags: c

Hello I am computer science major in florida, just curious to why my code wont give me an actual number, each time I run it and i enter an input i get 0.00

```
int fahrenheit;
printf("Enter the temperature in degrees fahrenheit \n");
scanf("%d",&fahrenheit);
double celsius;
celsius = (5/9) * ((fahrenheit - 32));
printf("The degrees in celsius is %lf",celsius);
```

Comment: Try `5.0/9`. What you have is integer division which results in `0` for `5/9`.

Comment: yooo thank you so much It i spent 3 hours trying to figure that out lol thank you !!!!!!